# How to find out where the loaded files of ClearCase views?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We use both ClearCase UCM and base. One of the open questions we have is, how to find out where the loaded files of snapshot views are reside, by a given path of view storage directory?

e.g. We have a view located in `C:\views\myview.vws`

Sometimes the equivalent loaded files are in `C:\views\myview` directory, but sometimes not. I'm looking for a way to find where it is.

I tried to find it out by `cleartool lsview -l` and `cleartool desc` - does not help.
The Windows registry does not provide this answer as either (AFAIK).

Answer (score 1):

I confirm there is not information where a snapshot view (UCM or not) actually resides.

You need to realize that by simply copying the `.view.dat` (hidden) file that you can see at the root directory of any of your snapshot view, you will make the destination directory (in which you copy the `.view.dat` file) the root of your snapshot view.

Copy it to three different directories, and you have the *same* snapshot view replicated three times!
Copy it to `C:\Windows\System32`, and that directory becomes a snapshot view root directory!

You best bet is to search for those `.view.dat` (or `view.dat` on Windows): those files contains the uid (unique id) of the view, allowing you to reconcile that with what you see within the view storage.